# How to get form input value from evaluateJavaScript method in WKWebView in swift 4?

Tags: swift4, wkwebview

In my project UIWebView is being used for display forms and when user input data and submit the form, the javascript method of UIWebView is being used to get resulting string as:

```
let formstring: String = formWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('json').value;") ?? ""
```

in above formstring I get this as result:

```
{"personnel":"testName","textarea1":"testxyz","status":"1"}
```

Now I need to migrate from UIWebview to WKWebview as UIWebview is deprecated now. For this I have implemented the WKWebview and the form is displaying in it. but when I try to get value from javascript I get nothing as:

```
formWebView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('json').value;", completionHandler: {(result,error)in
            if error != nil{
            print(result)
                formstring = result as! String
            }
        })
```

In above lines 'result' is always nil. 
May be I am unable to understand what exactly is going on with UIWebView or I can't find out how to get output from WKWebView. The thing is I need to get form input from javascript in my code. 
How to get it?